# JTextfield not updating till end of JButton action performed method? Tried using repaint,sleep still no use

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, netbeans-7

Hi I am trying for an application that reads and writes into excel on clicking run `JButton`. I am using a `JTextField` to give status (started / completed). Everthing is going well except `JTextField` not being updated till the end.

Based on previous answers I tried following.
 1)repaint `JTextField`variable.
 2)validate `JTextField`variable.
 3)validate `JPanel`variable.
 4)Tried to put process for sleep while till update happens.

Here is the code inside `ActionPerformed` method of run `JButton`

```
   private void RunButton_ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    status_val.setText("Started");
    status_val.repaint();
    status_val.validate();
    jPanel1.repaint();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(7000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Intiall_Caller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    try {
        //function to read and write into file
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Intiall_Caller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    status_val.setText("Completed");
}
```

Edit 1:
Just now I observed that the update on `JTextField` is not happening (delayed) till the end of `ActionPerformed`. All though I am not completely sure I think this could be the reason.

Comment: @JB NIzet my purpose using `sleep` itself is to look if could help in updating dynamically, or else I do not need sleep. I tried even without `sleep`.

Comment: That doesn't change anything. While you're executing code inside actionPerformed, you're using the event dispatch thread, and thus prevent it from repaining the screen. So if you want to repaint the screen multiple times, the long code must be done in another thread. Use a SwingWorker.

Comment: Now i tried removing `sleep` what I observed is the `JTextField` is updated after the file_read/write_method,or more specifically at the end of `ActionPerformed` method. I think `sleep` has nothing do with update or atleast in my case(code).

Comment: It doesn't matter if you use sleep or something else what takes time. What matters is that you block the event dispatch thread.

Comment: Here Í got the solution as you guys suggested [SwingWorker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/977740/swing-cant-get-jbutton-to-update-repaint-not-working?rq=1)